# How can I get previous value java?

Tags: java, android, string, stringbuilder

I have tow `Spinner dropDown` on my `layout` when user select each of spinner I'll take an id from `spinner`,and I have a class that I send these Ids to it class .

the `getID.class` :

```
public class getID {
private String tagID = "105358";

    public getID tagID(String tagID) {

        this.tagID += "," + tagID;

        return this;
    }
public URL build() throws MalformedURLException {
    return new URL(
            String.format("%s",
                          tagID));
     }
}
```

**Problem :**

But when I select an item on second spinner I lost the first Value of the first spinner .

I send my value to class with this code:

```
URL url = new getID(Const.URLMedia)
                                .tagID("10")
                                .build();
```

For example when I select an item on first spinner(for exam I send 10 value) in other class I see :

```
105358,10
```

when I select an Item on second spinner(for exam I send 85 value) in other class I see :

```
105358,85
```

But I need to :

```
105358,10,85
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are creating a new instance of `getID` everytime:

```
URL url = new getID(Const.URLMedia)
                                .tagID("10")
                                .build();
```

so when you select the first spinner you get `105358,10` and when you select second, your code will again create new instance of `getID` and you get `105358,5` so simply create a single `getID` instance instead of creating a new one every time.

```
class Activity ..{
getID  url;

         @Override
          oncreate (Bundle saveinstance){
          url=new getID();
        }
  }
```

Now simple appends the value

```
URL url = obj.tagID(StringValue).build();
```

plus i can't see any `constructor` for this `getID(Const.URLMedia)`,seems like missing.

> Best Practices for some unexpected cases to avoid broken URL(if
>   sequence matter):

**if user select 2nd spinner instead of first** : you can create new `getID` object inside `onclick` of first spinner plus set the default value of 2nd spinner.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to keep track of the two sliders (I have added a constructor):

```
public class getID {
private String tagID;
private String init;
private String firstSlider;
private String secondSlider;

public getID setFirstSlider(String value) {
    firstSlider = value;
    return this;
}
public getID setSecondSlider(String value) {
    secondSlider = value;
    return this;
}

public getID(String init) {
    this.init = init;
    tagID = "" ;
    firstSlider = "";
    secondSlider = "";      
}

    public getID tagID() {

        this.tagID = init + "," + firstSlider + "," + secondSlider;

        return this;
    }
public URL build() throws MalformedURLException {
    return new URL(
            String.format("%s",
                          tagID));
     }
}
```

Then you can use the class like this:

```
        try {
        getID myID = new getID("105358") ;
        URL url = myID.setFirstSlider("10").setSecondSlider("20").tagID().build();
        System.out.println("url: " + url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
    }
```

There are other ways to do it, for example by removing the tagID() function and the tagID String and calling directly build() since all the info is available:

```
public URL build() throws MalformedURLException {
    return new URL(
            String.format("%s,%s,%s",
                          init, firstSlider, secondSlider));
     }
}
```